# Can not call sp_detach_db on a database that is offline

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I can run this command in SqlManager to detach the db

```
ALTER DATABASE mydb SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

GO

dbo.sp_detach_db @dbname = N'mydb',@keepfulltextindexfile = N'false'
```

When I use the same connection running the same commadn via ado.net fails with error:

```
The database 'mydb' can not be opened because it is offline
```

(Error is translated from german.)

The Ado.Net code is

```
            SqlCommand cmdOffline = new SqlCommand(@"ALTER DATABASE mydb SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE");
            cmdOffline.Connection = prepareMasterDBConnection;
            cmdOffline.ExecuteNonQuery();


            SqlCommand cmdDetach = new SqlCommand(@"dbo.sp_detach_db @dbname = N'mydb',@keepfulltextindexfile = N'false'");
            cmdDetach.Connection = prepareMasterDBConnection;
            cmdDetach.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The connection is set to master - DB and open. The first commadn exceutes sucessfully.

What is the difference here when calling the code from ado and from sql-manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to avoid conflicting connections while dropping it, rather than setting it offline before detaching, I would use the command, `ALTER DATABASE mydb SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` instead of setting it offline (and reverse it with `ALTER DATABASE mydb SET MULTI_USER`).

Comment: I maybe misread something. I read something like "If you want to attach and reattach database there is a problem because the db will be offline". I thought I have to set the db offline, but I guess it means the db will be offline because it is detached.

Answer (score 0):

Detach needs to do some stuff before it detaches. Like [s_detach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188031(SQL.90).aspx) says (my bold)

> @skipchecks =  'skipchecks'
>
> Specifies whether to skip or run
>   UPDATE STATISTIC. skipchecks is a
>   nvarchar(10) value, with a default
>   value of NULL. To skip UPDATE
>   STATISTICS, specify true. To
>   explicitly run UPDATE STATISTICS,
>   specify false.
>
> **By default, UPDATE STATISTICS is
>   performed** to update information about
>   the data in the tables and indexes in
>   the SQL Server 2005 Database Engine.
>   Performing UPDATE STATISTICS is useful
>   for databases that are to be moved to
>   read-only media.

When it's offline, you can't do that...